Post request not working, get and delete do with Express JS and Vue
I'm following this tutorial to get a basic app setup and everything is working great for me expect the post request and I'm out of ideas.
Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HkIGAqAP1GY
This is pretty recreatable since there's the tutorial but I'm hoping I've just been looking at it too long and that's why I can't see what's wrong.
Running refreshData() and deleteNote() run perfectly, and the format is the same, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong for the post request to not be found on the api side.
Here's the call in the Network tab

Express JS Api
var Express = require("express");
var Mongoclient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var cors = require("cors");
var multer= require("multer");


var app = Express();
app.use(cors());

var CONNECTION_STRING=<removing for privacy>;

var DATABASENAME="gifttracker";
var database;

app.listen(5038, () => {
    console.log("app listen");
    Mongoclient.connect(CONNECTION_STRING).then((client) => {
        database = client.db(DATABASENAME);
        console.log('Mongo DB Donnection Successful');
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error connecting to MongoDB: ', err)
    });
})

app.get('/api/gifttracker/GetNotes', async (req, res) => {
    let collection = await database.collection("todo");
    let results = await collection.find({}).toArray();
    res.send(results).status(200);
});

app.post('/api/gifttracker/AddNotes',multer().none(), async (req, res) => {
    console.log("addnote api", req); //this does NOT get printed
    let collection = await database.collection("todo");
    collection.count({}, function(error, num){
        collection.insertOne({
            id:(num+1).toString(),
            desc:req.body.newNotes
        })
        res.json("Added successfully");
    })
})

app.delete('/api/gifttracker/DeleteNotes', async (req, res) => {
    let collection = await database.collection("todo");
    collection.deleteOne({
        id:req.query.id
    });
    res.json("Deleted Successfully");
})

Vue App UI
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>To Do</h1>
    <input id="newNote"/>
    <button @click="addNote()">Add</button>
    <p v-for="note in notes" :key="note.id">
      {{ note.desc }}
      <button @click="deleteNote(note.id)">Delete</button>
    </p>  
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
const API_URL="http://localhost:5038/";
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  data() {
    return {
      notes: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async refreshData() {
      axios.get(API_URL+'api/gifttracker/GetNotes').then((res) => {
        this.notes = res.data;
      })
    },
    async addNote() {
      var note = document.getElementById("newNote").value;
      console.log("add note", note); //this gets printed
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("newNotes", note);
      console.log("form data", formData); // so does this
      axios.post(API_URL+"api/gifttracker/AddNotes", formData).then((res) => {
        this.refreshData();
        alert(res.data);
      }).catch((err)=> {
        console.log("err",err);
      })
    },
    async deleteNote(id) {
  console.log("delete note", id);
  axios.delete(API_URL+"api/gifttracker/DeleteNotes?id="+id).then((res) => {
    this.refreshData();
    alert(res.data);
  })
},
  },
  mounted() {
    this.refreshData();
  }
}
</script>



Please add the response of that request.

you're not sending application/x-www-form-urlencoded, so why are you using multer middleware?

run far away from any Vue tutorial instructing you to use document interface to get values directly from the DOM instead of actual Vue features like v-model or v-bind...  AI voices are also another red flag.

@BrahmaDev the response is empty. "Failed to load response data: No data found"

@yoduh  yeah I know the tutorial isn't great, but I figured it was a good starting point to just get something out there since I work with Vue so I can fix it, but my dev startup at home is nonexistant. Maybe not..

@JaromandaX just copying tutorial as a starting point. I know it's better to use express json

I figured it out. I just needed to get rid of the extra stuff the tutorial mentioned and pass my values back as json
API
app.use(Express.json());

app.post('/api/gifttracker/AddNotes', async (req, res) => {
    console.log("addnote api", req.body);
    let collection = await database.collection("todo");
    collection.insertOne({desc: req.body.note})
    res.send(req.body.note + " added").status(200);
})

UI
async addNote() {
      var note = document.getElementById("newNote").value;
      console.log("add note", note);
      let json = { note: note};
      axios.post(API_URL+"api/gifttracker/AddNotes", json).then((res) => {
        this.refreshData();
        alert(res.data);
      }).catch((err)=> {
        console.log("err",err);
      })
    },

